# Simple.Odata Client using windows authentification

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, windows-authentication, simple.odata.client

It is possible to use Simple Odata Client to request my Odata service (hosted by  Asp.Net MVC) using windows authentifaction ?

Simple Odata client require Credentials :

```
public ODataClient(ODataClientSettings settings);
public ODataClientSettings(Uri baseUri, ICredentials credentials = null);
```

And the only example I have found is based on a newtworkCredentials :
https://github.com/object/Simple.OData.Client/blob/master/Simple.OData.Client.IntegrationTests/WebApiTests.cs

```
public class WebApiWithAuthenticationTests : WebApiTestsBase
{
    private const string _user = "tester";
    private const string _password = "tester123";

    public WebApiWithAuthenticationTests()
        : base(new ODataClientSettings()
        {
            BaseUri = new Uri("http://va-odata-integration.azurewebsites.net/odata/secure"), 
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_user, _password)
        })
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [`CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.credentialcache.defaultcredentials?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Net_CredentialCache_DefaultCredentials) property like this.

```
public class WebApiWithAuthenticationTests : WebApiTestsBase
{    
    public WebApiWithAuthenticationTests()
        : base(new ODataClientSettings()
        {
            BaseUri = new Uri("http://va-odata-integration.azurewebsites.net/odata/secure"), 
            Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        })
    {
    }
}
```